# Display questions from an array in order on a button press in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, uibutton

I am new to learning iOS Swift, so apologies if this is easy.

My apps first page has a simple layout:

UILabel (my question)
UITextField (where the user writes their answer)
UIButton (active once the user has input into the text field)

I have made an array of 4 questions. I am trying to code that when the user presses the UIButton, it will display the next question in the array, as long as the text field has been populated.

This is what i have so far:

```
@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var questionLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var buttonLabel: UIButton!

let questions = ["Where are you going?", "Do you know what city?", "What are you doing there?", "When do you go?"]


@IBAction func nextButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    textField.hidden = false
    textField.placeholder = "Country"


    for var i = 0; i < 5; i++ {
        questionLabel.text = questions[0]
    }

    buttonLabel.setTitle("Next", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

  }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //keyboard
    textField.delegate = self

    buttonLabel.setTitle("Get Started", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    questionLabel.text = ""

    // Hides the text field
    textField.hidden = true

    // Hides the image background for the text field
    barImage.hidden = true

}
```

I am able to make it so when the user presses the 'Get started' button, it changes the button text to say 'Next', displays the textField and the first question in the array.

But i'm having trouble figuring out how to move to the next question once the user has inputted an answer and pressed the Next button.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a property called `currentQuestionIndex` to keep track of where you are in the array and increase it when you click the button:

```
var currentQuestionIndex = 0

@IBAction func nextButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    textField.hidden = false
    textField.placeholder = "Country"

    questionLabel.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]

    if currentQuestionIndex < questions.count {
         ++currentQuestionIndex
         buttonLabel.setTitle("Next", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
        (sender as UIButton).userInteractionEnabled = false
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the Next button disabled unless there is an answer in the text field? I have tried things like:      If textField == nil { nextButton.enabled = false} - but it doesn't seem to work...? Thanks

Comment: sure `textField.userInteractionEnabled = false`

Comment: Hi, when I run the line above, it just disabled the user typing in the textfield. What i would like, is the 'Next' button to be disabled until something has been written in the textfield.

Comment: `userInteractionEnabled` works for all descendants of `UIView`, so just apply it to `UIButton`

Comment: Hi, I'm sure it's me being stupid, but where ever I place it, I can't get it to do what I need. Could you show me where it needs to go in the code above please? Much appreciated